# Don't get information in new page ( ionic + angularjs )

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router, ui-sref

I'm trying to send parameters to another page with the instruction ( ui- sref = " forgotpassword ( {id : item.id } ) " ) but in the new page i don´t get the parameters that i sent

And why thes tabs not displaying in tne new page ?

Any help please

code:

```
   .state("app",{
      templateUrl: "templates/app.html",
      url: "/app",
      abstract: true
    })
    .state('forgotpassword', {
    url: "/forgot-password/:id",
    templateUrl: "templates/forgot-password.html",
    controller: "forgotpasswordCtrl"
})

.controller('forgotpasswordCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, RawData) {
    $scope.rawData = RawData.get($stateParams.id);
})

.factory('RawData', function() {
    // Might use a resource here that returns a JSON array

    // Some fake testing data   
    var rawData = [{
      "id": "1",
      "tipo": "evento",
      "titulo": "Esta es una noticia de dos líneas principal",
      "bg": "fondo-not.png",
      "bgdetail": "noti-detalle.png",
      "fec": "ABRIL, 14,  2:56 AM",
      "com": "Backpack from Très Bien. Made in collaboration with Haerfest. Nylon body with top zip closure. Leather bottom. Outer compartment with zip closure and leather trims. Adjustable shoulder straps in leather. Metal hardware. Lined with cotton. Inner compartments. Outer logo branding."
    }];

    return {
        all: function() {
            return rawData;
        },
        get: function(id) {
            for (var i = 0; i < rawData.length; i++) {
                if (rawData[i].id === parseInt(id)) {
                    return rawData[i];
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
});
```

ion-item :

```
<ion-view title="Noticias">
    <ion-content ng-controller="noticiasCtrl" style="top:0">          
          <ion-list>
            <ion-item ng-repeat="item in rawData.slice(1, n)" class="item-noticias overlay" ng-style="{'background':'url(img/'+item.bg +') no-repeat center', 'background-size':'cover'}">                
                <div class="overlay" ui-sref="forgotpassword({ id: item.id })">       
                    <span class="tipo">{{ item.tipo }}</span>
                    <span class="titulo">{{ item.titulo }}</span>
                    <span class="link">Leer mas <img src="img/right-arrow.png"></span>                    
                </div>                        
            </ion-item>
          </ion-list>         
      </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

new page:

```
<ion-view title="forgotpassword">
  <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
    <button class="button" ng-click="$ionicGoBack($event)"></button>
  </ion-nav-buttons>
  <ion-content style="top:0">    
    <div class="header-image" ng-style="{'background':'url(img/'+bgd +') no-repeat center', 'background-size':'cover'}">
    <div class="overlayPrinD"> 
      <div class="overlayPrinSecD">                 
            <span class="tipo">{{ tipo }}</span>
            <span class="titulo">{{ tit }}</span>                               
      </div>                
    </div>       
  </div>
  <p class="fec">{{ fec }}</p>
  <p class="texto">{{ com }}</p>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

tabs:

app.html:

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-positive tabs-icon-only tabs-color">

    <ion-tab title="Noticias" icon-off="noticia" icon-on="noticia2" ui-sref="app.noticias">

        <ion-nav-view name="app-noticias">

        </ion-nav-view>

    </ion-tab>

    <ion-tab title="Servicios" icon-off="serv" icon-on="serv2" ui-sref="app.servicios">

        <ion-nav-view name="app-servicios">

        </ion-nav-view>

    </ion-tab>

    <ion-tab title="Información" icon-off="infor" icon-on="infor">

        <ion-nav-view>

        </ion-nav-view>

    </ion-tab>

    <ion-tab title="Reserva" icon-off="reser" icon-on="reser">

        <ion-nav-view>

        </ion-nav-view>

    </ion-tab>

    <ion-tab title="Contacto" icon-off="cont" icon-on="cont">

        <ion-nav-view>

        </ion-nav-view>

    </ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you wanted show direct view inside your `nav-view`. Your state shouldn't be using `views` then.

**Code**

```
.state('forgotpassword', {
    url: "/forgot-password/:id",
    templateUrl: "templates/forgot-password.html",
    controller: "forgotpasswordCtrl"
})
```

Comment: ok thank, it wor fine, but i have another problem, in the new page i don´t get the parameters that i sent, this is my code, the code is in my edit question..

Comment: do use `$state.params.id` instead of `$stateParams.id` issue here https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/136

Comment: I used only $state but its not work, i put console.log in "return rawData[i]" but not show anything

Comment: @user3810167 are you able to access the `id` parameter from URL?

Comment: my url show this : "www/#/forgot-password/2" the number is the id

Comment: @user3810167 the id is accessible inside controller? or the problem is different than this?

Comment: in the controller: .controller('forgotpasswordCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, RawData) {
    $scope.rawData = RawData.get($stateParams.id); 
}) when the "for" make the return, this not return anything, all the code is up

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85471/discussion-between-pankaj-parkar-and-user3810167).

Comment: @user3810167 It should be `.controller('forgotpasswordCtrl', function($scope, $state, RawData) { $scope.rawData = RawData.get($state.params.id); })`

Comment: i resolved it, the problem was: if (rawData[i].id === parseInt(id)) and the solution was put a parseInt in : if (parseInt(rawData[i].id) === parseInt(id))

Comment: the problem now is that the tabs not showing in the new page, why ?

Comment: @user3810167 which tabs are not loading..I don't see any tab in your current code..then how can I answer on that?

Comment: show my edit up, there is the code to tabs, the tabs in the new page are not displaying

Comment: @user3810167 you are really increasing the context of your question..going on adding a things after answering..